# Parametric plot of the critical points of an ODE

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, ecology

I have a single ODE of the form

```
x'[t] = -(y*n*n + z*n) x[t] + w (1-x[t]) x[t]
```

where the second part of the ODE is the logistic growth with the maximum allowed population set to 1 and growth rate equals to w.

The first part is some sort of polynomial exploitation/growth function whose effect is defined according to `y, z` and `n`.

I am only interested in the values of `x[t]` within the range [0, 1].

I am able to plot and manipulate the stream plot for it:

```
x'[t] == f[t, x[t]];
fo1[t_, x_] := -x*(y*n^2 + z*n) + w (1 - x) x /. {w -> 1};
Manipulate[
  Show[
    StreamPlot[{1, fo1[t, x] /. {y -> my, z -> mz, n -> mn}}, {t, 0,25}, {x, -0.25, 1.25}, 
    VectorPoints -> Automatic, 
    VectorStyle -> Black, StreamStyle -> Orange, 
    VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[0.01], ImageSize -> Medium, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {-0.25, 1.15}}]],
  {{mn, 1, "[0,100]"}, 0, 1},
  {{mz, 1.05, "[-1,1]"}, -2, 2},
  {{my, -0.345, "[-1,1]"}, -2, 2}]
```

from which it can be seen that according to the parameter `y, z` and `n` (assuming `w` ia fixed) the number and type of the critical points change.

With the given values, for instance, there is an unstable point at 0 and a stable point at ~0.3

What I would like to achieve is a parametric plot with two of the above parameters on the Cartesian axes (e.g., `y` and `z`) and which divides the plot into regions according to the number of critical points present in it. If possible, I would also like to each region with its type.

For instance something like what is shown in the figure below:

[image: plot example]

So far I am not able to go any further than making the stream plot. I have no idea on how to proceed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could use ParametricNDSolve. What is the initial value x[0]? The condition for a critical point is `x'[t]=0 ` ?

Comment: Is `u[t]` supposed to be `x[t]`?

Comment: The ODE seems to have a 1D phase space -- there are no saddles. Generically, you have either 1 source/1 sink.

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes, I apologize for the mistake. And yes I know that there is no saddle in this specific case. Thanks.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann the initial value `x[0]` might have different values. But for now, it is okay to fix it (e.g. 0.5).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `n` represent?

Comment: @ChrisK it represents the population size

Comment: @Dario If `n` is population size, what's `x`?

Comment: @ChrisK (a different) population size, not human controlled as n (i.e. n are robots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analysis is easier if we define a new compound parameter, `c=y*n*n + z*n`.  The resulting equation is still a logistic equation, with two equilibria:

```
Solve[0 == -c x + (1 - x) x, x]
(* {{x -> 0}, {x -> 1 - c}} *)
```

The trivial equilibrium is unstable when $c<1$ and stable when $c>1$.  The latter situation corresponds to the second equilibrium being negative, so that's the condition for one vs two meaningful (non-negative) equilibria.

Now we can substitute the definition of `c` in terms of `y` and `z` to solve for  the critical boundary between these cases:

```
Solve[1 == (y*n^2 + z*n), y]
(* {{y -> (1 - n z)/n^2}} *)
```

This is a line, which looks like:

```
n=1;
Plot[(1 - n z)/n^2, {z, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {z, y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Above the line, there is only `x=0` which is stable.  Below the line, `x=0` is unstable and there is a positive, stable equilibrium.